# Hankel transform of certain $\pm1$ sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

The present discussion finds its motivation in the comments by Ira Gessel to [my earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448411/products-involving-exponents-of-tribonacci-numbers). More specifically,
$$\prod_{i\geq0}(1-x^{2^i})=\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^{s_2(k)}x^k$$
where $s_2(k)$ is the sum of the binary digits of $k$. Side remark: $\{(-1)^{s_2(k)}\}_{k\geq0}$ is known as the Thue-Morse sequence.

Given a sequence $(a_k)$, the **determinant** of the matrix $M$ having entries $M_{i,j}=a_{i+j-2}$ (for $1\leq i,j\leq n$) is called its Hankel transform.  Several authors studied the Hankel transform of the Thue-Morse sequences noted above, see [Hao Fu and Guo-Niu Han](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04370.pdf) and references therein. Fu-Han explored other sequences arising from (I'll only focus on three of them)
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{k\geq0}{\color{blue}a_k}x^k &=\prod_{i\geq0}(1-x^{2^i}), \\
\sum_{k\geq0}{\color{blue}b_k}x^k &=\prod_{i\geq0}(1-x^{3^i}-x^{2\cdot3^i}), \\
\sum_{k\geq0}{\color{blue}c_k}x^k &=\prod_{i\geq0}(1-x^{5^i}-x^{2\cdot5^i}-x^{3\cdot5^i}+x^{4\cdot5^i}).
\end{align*}
Let $t_{p,r}(k)$ denote number of $r$'s in base-$p$ digital expansion of $k$. By contrast to Fu-Han, I like to define three other sequences
$$\tilde{{\color{red}a}}_k=(-1)^{t_{2,1}(k)}, \qquad
\tilde{{\color{red}b}}_k=(-1)^{t_{3,2}(k)}, \qquad
\tilde{{\color{red}c}}_k=(-1)^{t_{5,2}(k)}.$$

First, observe that $t_{2,1}(k)=s_2(k)$ and $\tilde{a}_k=a_k$. So, the Hankel transforms of the latter are equal. On the other hand, although all sequences are $\pm1$, the pair $\tilde{b}_k$ and $b_k$ as well as the pair $\tilde{c}_k$ and $c_k$ are unequal sequences in general. Take, for instance,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\geq0}{\color{blue}b}_kx^k&=1+x-x^2+x^3+x^4-x^5-x^6-x^7+x^8+x^9+\cdots \\
\sum_{k\geq0}\tilde{{\color{red}b}}_kx^k
&=1-x-x^2-x^3+x^4+x^5-x^6+x^7+x^8-x^9+\cdots
\end{align*}

> **QUESTION.** Are the Hankel transforms of $\tilde{{\color{red}b}}_k$ and ${\color{blue}b}_k$ equal? Are the Hankel transforms of $\tilde{{\color{red}c}}_k$ and ${\color{blue}c}_k$ are equal? Experiments suggest they are equal.

**Remark.** For reference, here are the sequences of Hankel determinants ($n\geq1$) associated with $\{{\color{blue}a_k}\}_{k\geq0}, \{{\color{blue}b_k}\}_{k\geq0}, \{{\color{blue}c_k}\}_{k\geq0}$, respectively,
\begin{align*}
&+1, -2, +4, +8, -16, -32, -64, +128, -256, -1536, \dots \\
&+1,-2,-4,+8,+16,-32,-64,+128,+4864,-9728,\dots \\
&+1,-2,-4,+8,+48,-96,-320,+640,+1792,+512,\dots
\end{align*}